# Azure Active Directory - UI > API - 401 Error

Tags: azure-active-directory, bearer-token

Good Day,

Currently I have a single tenent with a React UI and .NET Core Apis secured by Azure Active Directory without any problems.

We have recently moved to a new Azure Tenent, new Active Directory etc.  I have create two new App Registrations, one single App Service for UI and one for API.  I have linked the App Service to AAD (UI = UI App Registration, API = API App Registration).

The problem is the API is getting a 401 error and I think see that in the original tenent the Bearer token is in a JWT format but in the new instance it's not, I believe it my be a graph api access key.

**New Tenent:**
Authorization: Bearer PAQABAAAAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrQvEQVbZEMD8su-tIp9k2bTFUTort7SZgeDI52P6KRYefHgtmj4YrecgUKZJ2wylGuhvIzIz642n7Sg0VMU1RwKtrzWlaMqK62CaSoJcstxiEf6 *****

**Orginal Tenent:**
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsImtpZCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI3OThkN2ZkOC0zODk2LTQxOGMtOTQ0Ny0wNGFlNTQ2OGFkNDIiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3N0cy53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC83ZDE3NTU3Ni03Y2Y3LTQyMDctOTA5My0wNmNiNmQyZDIwNjAvIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE2NDUyNzExLCJuYmYiOjE2MTY0NTI3MTEsImV4cCI6MTYxNjQ1NjYxMSwiYWNyIjoiMSIsImFpbyI6IkFTUUEyLzhUQUFBQU9mejhPZHp *****

Please someone kindly enought to provide some guidance / input where I am going wrong.

Regards
Paul.

Comment: have you tried sending the authentication call via Fiddler and reading the raw response? I wonder if there are any interesting details in there except a bare 401...

Comment: Not really, only getting the following "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."  If I turn off Auth for API, everything works as expected.

Comment: I see. I suggest that you share your request url/body/query string or code if using a client library, so we know what endpoint are you calling.

Comment: In your original (pre-migration) domain setup - did you have two AD applications - one for the app and one for the API ?   Or did you have one AD app for both.

Comment: I created the post migration the same as the original (but this was done by someone else) so there are two app registrations, one for ui and one for api.

Comment: Just noticed the following (only on initial request, straight after login): Access to internal resource at 'https://login.windows.net/*/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F<SITE NAME>%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=*&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=*&state=redir%3D%252Fmanifest.json' (redirected from 'https://***-prod.azurewebsites.net/manifest.json') from origin 'https://<SITE NAME>.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Which account do you use to sign in for the new tenant? A work account or guest account or personal Microsoft account?

Comment: I sign in with my work account.

Comment: Paul have you solved the issue? We are facing the same....

Answer (score 3):

Either you have to use the endpoint **version 2** with this authority : [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/**v2.0**](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/v2.0)

Version 2 does not support the resource parameter, but scopes contain the full URI. For example: https://contoso.com/api/Employees.Read.All

Or you use the endpoint **version 1** (default if you don't specify a version [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D)) and you have to specify an additional **`resource`** parameter. Otherwise, the access token is not a JWT.

For example, if your web API's application ID URI is `https://contoso.com/api` and the scope name is `Employees.Read.All`:

[image: Scopes]

Then, in a .NET client, you can set the `OpenIdConnectOptions.Resource` property.

In a JS client with [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki#other-optional-settings), the configuration should be :

```js
scope: 'openid profile email Employees.Read.All',
extraQueryParams: {
  resource: 'https://contoso.com/api'
}
```

In [App Service auth configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-windows#configure-app-service-to-return-a-usable-access-token), you can use **`additionalLoginParams`**

```json
"additionalLoginParams": ["response_type=code", "resource=https://contoso.com/api"]
```

If you did not use a custom application ID URI, it may look like
`api://868662dd-3e28-4c7f-b7d5-7ec02ac9c601`

[Quickstart: Configure an application to expose a web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `scope` is incorrect.

You should **Expose an API** in your API App Registration and then add it as a permission in your UI App Registration. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-dotnet-native-aspnet).

And when you try to call the `'https://login.windows.net/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize` endpoint, you need to specify the `scope` to include `api://{app id of the API App Registration}`. For example: `api://{app id of the API App Registration} openid profile email`. Then the access token would be for calling your API.

At last, for CORS issue, please configure the CORS as `*` in your web app to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this step: [Configure App Service to return a usable access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-windows#configure-app-service-to-return-a-usable-access-token)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this problem occurs, when you try to authorize against version 1 of the endpoint.
Instead of calling

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize
```

call

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

You might be required to set something like "metadata URL" in you authorization library to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your builder follows this order...lifted from our API program.cs

These must be in order of
UseRouting -> UseAuthentication -> UseAuthorisation -> MapControllers

```
>     app.UseRouting()
>     app.UseAuthentication()
>     app.UseAuthorization()
>     app.MapControllers()
```

If app.UseAuthentication and app.UseAuthorization are not in this order in statement position you Will get 401 Unauthorised as at 01/2023 .Net 6 Core.